# Returning a dynamic Json in a Rest Service

Tags: java, json, rest, spring-boot

I'm trying my hand on implementing a simple Restful Web Service using Spring Boot.

Currently, I want to parse an XML file to a Json object and return it as the response message. However I'm currently having problems defining the structure of the returned JSON object since it can vary depending on the XML file that I'm parsing.

This is a parsed XML-to-Json example of what I'm trying to return.

```
{
    "App": {
        "CR": {
            "Product": {
                "PRequest": {
                    "MF": "dfl3",
                    "Pri": "0",
                    "PC": "age",
                    "PCode": "Hca"
                }
            }
        },
        "SD": {
            "SDF": {
                "PRP": {
                    "_cCao": "str1234",
                    "_cSao": "str1234",
                    "_dao": "2012-12-13",
                    "_dCao": "2012-12-13",
                    "_dr": "2012-12-13",
                    "_nIDta": "str1234",
                    "_no": "1234"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a way to return a dynamic Json object whose structure is only defined at run time?

Comment: JSON does not have to have any rigid structure since you can serialize like everything into json.

Comment: Use JSON entites as for starters (depends on framework). You can always use Map<String,Object> to build structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish this very easily with `org.json`:

```
String xmlString = "<note><to>Bill</to><from>Ben</from><body>Hello!</body></note>";
JSONObject jsonObject = XML.toJSONObject(xmlString);
String jsonString = jsonObject.toString();

// Evaluates to:
// {"note":{"from":"Ben","to":"Bill","body":"Hello!"}}
```

This will turn an XML string into a JSONObject which you can then manipulate or turn into a JSON string.

If you're using Maven, you can add a dependency for `org.json` by adding this to your `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.json</groupId>
    <artifactId>json</artifactId>
    <version>20180813</version>
</dependency>
```